# VBA - Eval a string in a "me!" variable

Tags: string, vba, variables, eval

I have a problem in a VBA-Script in Access 2010.

I have a function to split a string into an array. I then want to evaluate all array elements (string). This elements represent form names that I want to use with the variable "me".

This is my code:

```
Private Sub enable_rec(rec)
    Dim r

    r = Split(rec, ", ")
    For Each rl In r
        'rl = Me.Eval(rl)
        MsgBox (rl)
        Me!rl.Enabled = True
        Me!rl.Locked = False
    Next
End Sub
```

I also tried this `Me!eval(rl).enabled = True`.

I updated the code as "Nicholas Post" suggested and now have this:

```
Private Sub enable_rec(rec)
    Dim r
    Dim ctrl As Control

    r = Split(rec, ", ")
    For Each rl In r
        ctrl = Me.Controls
        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox (rl)
            ctrl.Enabled = True
            ctrl.Locked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I get `run-time error '91': Object Variable or With Block not Set`

EDIT 2 - **Solved it myself**:
It works now with the following code

```
Private Sub enable_rec(rec)
    Dim arr As Variant, ctrl As Control

    arr = Split(rec, ", ")
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        'MsgBox (ctrl.Name) 'rl.ControlType
        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
            If IsInArrayLoop(ctrl.Name, arr) Then
                ctrl.Enabled = True
                ctrl.Locked = False
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

More Info about the function IsInArrayLoop [here](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/07/03/find-matching-data-in-array-speed-test/).

Answer (score 2):

You are close, but you have to get the object you are trying to work with by name. You would have to change your code to something like this:

```
Private Sub enable_rec(rec)
    Dim arrNames As Array = Split(rec, ", ")
    For Each strName As String In arrNames
        Dim ctrl As Control = Me.Controls(strName)
        If Not ctrl Is Nothing Then
            ctrl.Enabled = True
            ctrl.Locked = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I was using `Control` to test this, but Locked isn't part of that. SImply change it to the type you are using.

Comment: Thx for your answer. I'm getting an error: Objectvariable or With-Blockvariable not set (I translated it form german). What I forgot to say is, I'm working with Access 2010.